# module-info.class file is different in the module jar file and compiled module-info.class

Tags: java, maven, java-9, java-platform-module-system, .class-file

I have a simple module I'm building with `maven` and have a question about the resulting module jar. Here is the plugin section of my `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.8.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <maven.jar.plugin.version>3.1.2</maven.jar.plugin.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${java.version}</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.jar.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The project has the following structure:

```
mdl-standalone
    |
    |
    |__src/main/java
    |     |_com/test/mdl
    |     |     |_platform/Platform.java
    |     |     |_standalone/Standalone.java     
    |     |
    |     |_module-info.java
    |_pom.xml
```

`module-info.java`:

```
module com.test.mdl.standalone {
}
```

The `mvn clean install` command builds jar file and put compiled class files in the `target/classes` directory. I examined the following class files and noticed some difference:

`javap -v target/classes/module-info.class` (constant pool only)

```
  interfaces: 0, fields: 0, methods: 0, attributes: 2
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #8             // "module-info"
   #2 = Utf8               SourceFile
   #3 = Utf8               module-info.java
   #4 = Utf8               Module
   #5 = Module             #9             // "com.test.mdl.standalone"
   #6 = Module             #10            // "java.base"
   #7 = Utf8               11.0.4
   #8 = Utf8               module-info
   #9 = Utf8               com.test.mdl.standalone
  #10 = Utf8               java.base
```

`javap -v` of `module-info.class` extracted from the jar file:

```
  interfaces: 0, fields: 0, methods: 0, attributes: 3
Constant pool:
   #1 = Utf8               module-info
   #2 = Class              #1             // "module-info"
   #3 = Utf8               module-info.java
   #4 = Utf8               com.test.mdl.standalone
   #5 = Module             #4             // "com.test.mdl.standalone"
   #6 = Utf8               ModulePackages
   #7 = Utf8               com/test/mdl/standalone
   #8 = Package            #7             // com/test/mdl/standalone
   #9 = Utf8               com/test/mdl/platform
  #10 = Package            #9             // com/test/mdl/platform
  #11 = Utf8               java.base
  #12 = Module             #11            // "java.base"
  #13 = Utf8               11.0.4
  #14 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #15 = Utf8               Module
```

As can be seen there are difference in the constant pool and attribute numbers. In particular the `module-info.class` from the jar file contains [`ModulePackages`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.26) attribute with all the packages of the module packed within the jar.

This has some impact on determining the packages returned by `ModuleDescriptor::packages()`. In `case 2` the packages are simply extracted from the `ModulePackages` attribute the `case 1` in turn requires listing the directory tree and extracting package names.

***QUESTION:*** Which plugin sets the `ModulePackages` attribute of `module-info.class` in the jar file?

I suspect it is the `maven-jar-plugin`'s job, but how to configure it? In case, e.g. I want to reduce `module-info.class` size.

Comment: Please add the `module-info.java` file here...furthermore `maven-jar-plugin` does nothing with `module-info.class` file...and If I correctly remember about the code for maven-compiler-plugin it does neither...only the javac does something there...apart from that I'm not sure what you mean by: reduce `module-info.class` size?

Comment: @khmarbaise Added `module-info.java`.

Comment: @khmarbaise By reduce `module-info.class` I mean to strip the constant pool entries I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @khmarbaise _I correctly remember about the code for maven-compiler-plugin it does neither...only the javac does something there_ That makes sense, but anyway it would be nice to control the entries of the `module-info.class`'s constant pool in the resulting jar file (currently `javac module-info.class` does not add `ModulePackages` attribute in the class file which is sensible). Maybe there is some dedicated `javac` option?

Comment: I'm asking myself what kind of problem you are trying to solve...reducing the pool size in a module-info.class does not make sense from my point of view cause the entries like `java.base` and others are needed....apart from that if you say `javac module-info.java` is not the same as building a module which contains code and a `module-info.java` which is not equivalent to `javac module-info.java` cause the other sources needed also being compiled ... also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.26

Comment: Pretty sure the difference here is because packaging creates a modular jar, rather than simply a compiled module-info. See https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start#packaging

Comment: Yes the jar tool is the thing ...

Comment: @Michael Nice catch. I just checked it and it was exactly as you said. Thank you.

Comment: The `jar` tool adds the `ModulePackages` attribute, it can also add the `ModuleMainClass` attribute. In any case, the `ModulePackages` attribute is just an optimization to avoid need to scan the contents of the JAR file to determine the set of packages. The additional footprint of the module-info.class should not be an issue.

Comment: What a nightmare: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-275